# How to create text field like mail.app too, BCC or cc field in which address book contacts comes as hint on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos

create text field like mail.app too, BCC or cc field in which address book contacts comes as hint on OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really should ask [what have you tried before](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). 
But I'm not so cruel, check [NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and [Token Field Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555).